# SQL0206N "AS" is not valid in the context where it is used. SQLSTATE=42703

Tags: sql, db2, ssrs-2008

I have a SSRS report with sql query as below:

```
="select  ar_sum.client_id as Customer_Code,"& 
" ar_sum.bill_number as PRO_NO,"& 
" ar_sum.company_id as ORG,"& 
" tlorder.pick_up_by as Pick_Up_Date,"& 
" ar_sum.aging_date as Bill_Date,"& 
" ar_sum.aging_date  as Invoice_Date,"&

Switch(
    Parameters!CompName.Value = "355", " case when tlorder.pick_up_by is null then ar_sum.adj_amt else ar_sum.orig_amt end",
    Parameters!CompName.Value = "301" or Parameters!CompName.Value = "354", " case when ((tlorder.pick_up_by is null) and (substr(ar_sum.bill_number,1,1) not in('1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0'))) then ar_sum.adj_amt else ar_sum.orig_amt end"
)&

" as Original_Amount,"&

" case when tlorder.pick_up_by is null then ar_sum.adj_amt else ar_sum.orig_amt end as Invoice_Amount,"& 
" case when tlorder.pick_up_by is null then ar_sum.pay_amt  else (ar_sum.pay_amt - ar_sum.adj_amt) end as Amount_paid,"&
" ar_sum.bal_amt as Amount_Open,"& 
" ar_sum.currency_code as Currency_code"& 
" from TMWIN.ar_sum ar_sum"&
" left join TMWIN.tlorder tlorder on ar_sum.detail_line_id = tlorder.detail_line_id"&  
" where ar_sum.company_id  = " & Parameters!CompID.Value &
" and (ar_sum.bal_amt > 0.01 or ar_sum.bal_amt < -0.01)"&

Switch(
    Parameters!CompName.Value = "355", "",
    Parameters!CompName.Value = "301", " and ar_sum.ar_control_acct in ('301-1052-000-00-8','301-1053-000-00-8','301-1053-500-00-0','301-1052-500-00-0')", 
    Parameters!CompName.Value = "354", " and ar_sum.ar_control_acct not in ('301-1052-000-00-8','301-1053-000-00-8','301-1053-500-00-0','301-1052-500-00-0', '301-1052-000-00-7' ,'301-1053-000-00-7')")
```

When I run it, I got below error:

```
An error has occurred during report processing. (rsProcessingAborted)
Query execution failed for dataset 'DataSet1'. (rsErrorExecutingCommand)
ERROR [42S22] [IBM][CLI Driver][DB2/NT64] SQL0206N "AS" is not valid in the context where it is used. SQLSTATE=42703
```

I have tried to remove the AS word but no luck. Actually I did not change anything in the query and it is working before. And all my other queries have the AS word too.

Please help me I could not find where is the error.

Thanks for the help!

**EDITS:**

I am not really good at SSRS report. I found above query from below:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Show the __actual__ SQL sent to Db2, not the mechanics of how you build-up the SQL-string.  The real SQL will indicate the cause of the issue. Before sending the query to Db2, you could print or log the final SQL string.

Comment: Are you executing that sql or just building the string? I don;t know DB2 but in SQL Server you would do something like. `DECLARE @sql(varchar(max))` then `SET @SQL = [your code here]` then finally `EXEC (@SQL)` otherwise you are telling SSRS that you dataset is just a string containing a sql statement

Comment: @mao thanks for the help. I do not know how to check the actual query...

Comment: @AlanSchofield Hi Please check my edits. I guess it is sending the query to the DB2. It is using the ODBC connection to fetch the data from DB2

Comment: Try adding a big textbox and set the value to the same expression. Do this in a copy of the report as you will have to remove the problem dataset so the report can run. You will then see the string that is being passed and can check it for errors.